# How to create a letter box?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions, document

Our goal is to create a document library where all users can hand in documents, but only specific users can read those documents.

We've already tried to create specific rights. For example just add but not read. But this seams not possible.

If users could only read their own documents our problem would also be solved. But this option is only available for lists not for document libraries.

Does anyone have experience with this particular issue? I’ve already found users on the internet with similar issues but no accurate solution.

I'm thankfull for every input or possible solution.

Comment: You can create a library view. And put a filter [Created]=[Me]. They way users will only see there own documents.

Comment: I already had this thought. But I think that views don't secure the right use. What if a user access over the explorer?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a Document Library that has Document Approval enabled.

With that configuration, users can only see other documents once they've been Approved or have the Approve document permissions.

You just need to make sure only the correct people have the Approve permissions and that documents don't get approved by accident and become available for everyone.

*You might get people receiving messages that says a document with that name already exists, despite the fact that they cannot see the document.*

Comment: this seams like a decent workaround. Thx for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the Content Organizer might solve your problem. You need to activate the Content Organizer in the Site Settings and then configure settings for it. It will enable a Drop Off library for the users and then route the document to another library or even another site collection based upon the rules you define. That way your users who are uploading the documents don't need to be given permissions to the final destination library, only the specific users you want to read the docs.

More info:  [Content organizer](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Configure-the-Content-Organizer-to-route-documents-b0875658-69bc-4f48-addb-e3c5f01f2d9a?CorrelationId=372e96cf-3532-407e-b69c-cf0e6c29b8f8&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: I've not tried this yet but already had the idea to use the content organizer. Can the users still see their own uploaded documents that way?

Comment: It depends on what rights you apply to the destination library(s). At the very basic level, you could give them read access to the library, enabling them to view all documents in there. If you wanted to restrict it to just the docs they uploaded I think you'd be getting in to playing with audience targeting or managing share permissions at a document level (not the best thing to do for easy administration). I believe there are also 3rd party tools that allow metadata based security, perhaps you could look at that.